# How to prove that $\limsup X_n \leq \sup\{X_n\}$?

Tags: proof-writing

> How to prove that $\;\limsup\limits_{n\to\infty}X_n \leq \sup\limits_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\{X_n\}\;$?

I need to prove this and I don't know how to go about doing this.

Thank you for any help you can provide.

Comment: limcp? Do you mean $\limsup$?

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking.

Comment: Yes limsup{Xn} <= sup{Xn} sorry I will edit.

Comment: Could you also edit your question to be more clear, and show what you know? As it stands, your question may be closed for being either unclear or lacking detail.

Answer (score 2):

By definition $$\limsup\limits_{n\to\infty}X_n =\inf_k \sup_{n\geq k}X_n.$$ But of course $$\sup_{n\geq k}X_n \leq \sup_n X_n$$ for all $k$. Hence $$\inf_k \sup_{n\geq k}X_n \leq \sup_n X_n.$$

Answer (score 0):

**Alternative proof:**

$x=\limsup\limits_{n\to\infty}X_n\;$ only if a subsequence of $\;\left\{X_n\right\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ approaches $\;x\;$ and this subsequence is bounded above by $\sup\limits_{n\in\mathbb{N}}X_n$.